# Como enviar un campo file a través de URL (method get)?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, struts2

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<a class='A8' href="#" onclick="nuevaventana('myGenerator.action?indexList=${itStatus.count-1}');">
    Imprimir Doc
</a>
```

Aquí debe ir un campo que lleve un archivo cargado(una imagen), como lo hago?, esto para emular lo siguiente que se hace con POST:

```
<s:form id="generaDoc" action="createDoc" 
    method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <s:file id="fileFoto" name="fileFoto"
       onchange="verifyFotos(this);"
       style="width:100%;" onkeypress="return false;"/>
</s:form>
```

Esto es lo que se busca resolver, tanto el envió del campo `fileFoto` como el atributo `enctype` a traves de una URL.

No lo hago con POST por que como se darán cuenta con la URL abro un popup que al final recibe un PDF, con POST el PDF me queda la pagina principal o igual si saben como mandar el PDF a un popup después de crearlo serviría.

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme, de antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes la URL del PDF podes enviarlo a otra ventana o tab con Javascript usando

`window.open( 'URL_DEL_ARCHIVO.pdf' )`